# Parse for iOS using reset parse function

Tags: ios, parse-platform, change-password

I want to implement a function that allows users to reset their password. I already created a button that displays an alert view and asks for their email, but when I tap ok, it doesn't send an email.

What can I do?

```
-(IBAction)forget:(id)sender {

    [PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:@"email@example.com"];

    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email Address" message:@"Enter the email for your account:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput; 
    [alertView show];
}
```

Comment: where is your alert view delegate method?

Comment: It looks like you are resetting the password _before_ asking the user for their email!

Answer (score 3):

```
- (IBAction)forget:(id)sender {
    [self getEmail];
}

- (void)getEmail {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email Address" message:@"Enter the email for your account:" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;
        [alertView show];
    }

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex != [alertView cancelButtonIndex]) {
        UITextField *emailTextField = [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];
        [self sendEmail:emailTextField.text];
    }
}

- (void)sendEmail:(NSString *)email{
    [PFUser requestPasswordResetForEmailInBackground:email];
}
```

Comment: Good answer, but major problem with the code of alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: -- it triggers no matter whether "Cancel" or " OK" is pressed. You need to add a conditional...